# SQL Procedure Issues

Tags: plsql, oracle18c

I currently have two tables to work with (listed below).  Posted below is my code for my current procedure that take in an employeeID value and outputs their information.  I need to modify it to, in addition, list who the Department Chair is, and if the employee is already the department head it will list them as "Department Chair".

I've tried creating a separate view for telling who the dept chair is and calling on that in a LOOP, but am unsuccessful.  Pretty stuck here.

Comment: In order to provide a solution I will copy your code and fix it. Prior to posting it, I will need to test any solution I provide you with. In order to test it, I will need sample data. Please explain to me how to create and populate your sample database tables with your sample data, from the images you uploaded _without_ writing the SQL myself. If you don't know, then I suggest you read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace procedure emp_records (
    p_emp_id employees.employeeid%type
) is

    l_department_name        departments.departmentname%type;
    l_department_id          departments.departmentid%type;
    l_employee_first_name    employees.firstname%type;
    l_employee_last_name     employees.lastname%type;
    l_employee_employee_id   employees.employeeid%type;
    l_chair_id               departments.departmentchair%type;
    l_chair_name             varchar2(100);
begin
    -- For employee details
    select
        departmentname,
        firstname,
        lastname,
        employeeid,
        departmentid
    into
        l_department_name,
        l_employee_first_name,
        l_employee_last_name,
        l_employee_employee_id,
        l_department_id
    from departments d
    join employees e 
      on e.departmentid = d.departmentidusing
   where employeeid = p_emp_id;

   --For CHair details
  select departmentchair
    into l_chair_id
    from department
   where departmentid = l_department_id;

    if l_chair_id = l_employee_employee_id 
        then
            select 'Is the department chair' into l_chair_name from dual;
    else
        select 'Department Chair: ' || firstname || ' ' || lastname
          into l_chair_name
          from employees
         where employeeid = l_chair_id;
    end if;

    -- For output
    dbms_output.put_line('Information for Employee #' || p_emp_id);
    dbms_output.put_line('Full Name: ' || l_employee_first_name || ' ' || l_employee_last_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Department: ' || l_department_name);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_chair_name);
exception
    when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('No records found for this Employee.');
end;
/
```

Hope this will help.